# How to remove WordPress plugin activation message?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, message

I have a plugin that's not activated (it's a premium plugin) but I want it to stop showing on my wordpress panel. Is there some PHP code I can insert somewhere?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdX1A.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the plugin's functions.php file, you can usually find something like [is_active:false] and you can change that to true and get the premium things for free.

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot it quite clearly seems to show that the plugin is actually active, as there is a menu item called `WPForms`.

Deactivated plugins cannot show these update messages in the wordpress admin as their code is simply never ran while deactivated.

Just deactivate the plugin to hide the message.

Comment: Yeah but I need to use the plugin. I want to remove the message without disabling the plugin.

...and without buying a license. 

I strongly believe there is some "hack" I can insert as a PHP snippet or something like it.